# there is __cond_lock(x,c) define in compiler.h file , but no __cond_unlock(x,c) define?

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

In complier.h, there is a macro define as below:

```
# define __cond_lock(x,c)   ((c) ? ({ __acquire(x); 1; }) : 0)
```

But here I have a question, that is, where there is a __cond_lock definition, but does not define the corresponding __cond_unlock, then the variable on the release, how to keep consistent between __cond_lock and __cond_unlock?

And I checked the definition of function spin_trylock (), and it is used __cond_lock, but which also used a _spin_trylock function.in _spin_trylock function, after a few calls, it will use to __acquire function in this case, the equivalent of an operation, it carried out two calculations would lead Sparse detection warning message appears, after I wrote the code for an experiment to test my judgment, is indeed a warning message will appear, if I wrote it twice unlock instruction, there is no alarm information, but this is inconsistent as program running.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting critical sections using locking is up to the programmer. That means, if you hold a lock to protect a critical reason, you've must have to release the lock when you're finished.

There are various types of locking primitives inside Linux kernel like. spinlock(), spinlock_irq(), spin_trylock(). They have their own purposes. Now, spin_trylock() using __cond_lock inside of it, it's because to make sure, whether that particular lock is available for locking or it's been already taken. Take a look at few examples of how spin_trylock or __cond_lock is being used. For ex. at kernel/sched/fair.c::rebalance_domain (https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/fair.c?id=d8dfad3876e4386666b759da3c833d62fb8b2267#n5574) see how the balancing is used, it's been using spin_trylock() to hold the lock and while releasing doing it conditionally. Another example could be found at kernel/posix-timers.c, lock_timer() macro. If you closely look at the uses of lock_timer() you'll find how __cond_lock is being used inside kernel and hopefully your confusion will disappear.

In other words, __cond_lock is used to hold a lock conditionally and not being used directly. It's possible to check a particular lock before releasing the lock and this what has been done so far.